# adding layer on search for leaflet map changes polygon opacity

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I have two leaflet maps which are loaded with geojson on the basis of a search button click. This shows some polygons with a style opacity 0.3 so you can see the street names under the polygons.

It works great except that any additional searches and loading of polygons starts to change the opacity of the polygon, making it more solid so you cant read the names of the streets under the polygon.

I try clearing the geojson layer before adding to the map, but the issue persists.

I have created a rough code pen of the issue here:
https://codepen.io/joomkit/pen/xxXgLPJ?editors=1111

Essentially just click the search button to load the layer no need to fill the listener runs a function and gets static data.

I have tried various methods to remove layer. A second click on the search is meant to clear the layer and load a new one. In the example it's just reloading the original data but the opacity is clearly demonstrated.

Main code is also below.

```
var geoMap2;
var lamap = new L.Map("map2", {
  center: new L.LatLng(51.44094723464765, 0.048892332250943187),
  // center: new L.LatLng(39.75621,-104.99404),
  zoom: 14,
  maxZoom: 18
});
var osm2 = L.tileLayer(
  "https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/rastertiles/voyager/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png",
  {
    attribution:
      '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors &copy; <a href="https://carto.com/attributions">CARTO</a>',
    subdomains: "abcd",
    maxZoom: 18
  }
);
lamap.addLayer(osm2);

searchButton.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  let searchQuery = inputSearch.value;
  // searchOpenFunding(searchQuery);

  setLaMap(data);
});

function setLaMap(data) {
  removeLayers();

  let geojsonFeatureCollection2 = {
    type: "FeatureCollection",
    features: setFeatureCollection2(data)
  };

  geoMap2 = L.geoJSON(geojsonFeatureCollection2, {
    style: polyStyleLAMap,
    onEachFeature: function myonEachFeatureLaMap(feature, layer) {
      layer.myTag = "myGeoJSON";
    }
  }).addTo(lamap);

  lamap.setMaxBounds(lamap.fitBounds(geoMap2.getBounds()));
  lamap.setZoom(13);
}

var removeLayers = function () {
  lamap.eachLayer(function (layer) {
    if (layer.myTag && layer.myTag === "myGeoJSON") {
      lamap.removeLayer(layer);
      console.log("rem layer from ");
    }
  });
};

function setFeatureCollection2(data) {
  for (const [key, item] of Object.entries(data)) {
    // setup lealfet geojson collection from data mapit api is incomplete pe ritem so we build it here
    geoJsonFeatures2.push({
      type: "Feature",
      properties: {
        craftentryId: item.id,
        areaId: item.mapitAreaId,
        lsoacode: item.lsoacode,
        localauthority: item.localauthority,
        openForFunding: item.openForFunding,
        fundableRegion: item.fundableRegion,
        title: item.title,
        popupContent: ""
      },
      geometry: item.geojson
    });
  }
  return geoJsonFeatures2;
}

function polyStyleLAMap(feature) {
  return {
    fillColor: getFillColorLaMap(feature.properties.openForFunding),
    weight: 1,
    opacity: 1,
    color: getBorderColor(feature.properties.openForFunding),
    dashArray: "0",
    fillOpacity: 0.3
  };
}
function getFillColorLaMap(d) {
  return d === true ? "#FFFFFF" : d === false ? "#FED976" : "#FED976";
}
function getBorderColor(d) {
  return d === true ? "#0e9c12" : d === false ? "#adabab" : "#cccccc";
}
```

Comment: Take a look at it [remove-geojson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53155822/10424385)
ideally you would recreate the code on codepen.io or on codesandbox.io

Comment: @GrzegorzT. have added codepen and more code to post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here [https://codepen.io](https://codepen.io/Tomik23/pen/MWEJVxy)

The code I modified is:

```js
// 029A, 029C
function setLaMap(data) {
  removeLayers();

  let geojsonFeatureCollection2 = {
    type: "FeatureCollection",
    features: setFeatureCollection2(data),
  };

  console.log(geojsonFeatureCollection2);

  const geoMap2 = L.geoJSON(geojsonFeatureCollection2, {
    style: polyStyleLAMap,
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
      layer.myTag = "myGeoJSON";
    },
  });

  map.addLayer(geoMap2);

  map.setMaxBounds(map.fitBounds(geoMap2.getBounds()));
  // map.setZoom(13);
}

function removeLayers() {
  map.eachLayer((layer) => {
    if (layer.myTag && layer.myTag === "myGeoJSON") {
      console.log(layer);
      map.removeLayer(layer);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Seems obvious now - thank you. So create empty layer Group, add to map, remove layerGroup then set with real data. But what if the geoJsondata changes? It seems that if I change the data on the next search the geojson data layer still persists?

Comment: I did an example update. I delved a bit more.
The problem you had was that you had `let geoJsonFeatures2=[];` set globally, and every time you clicked, you added another object to the array. And with this, transparency was increased by one object, and therefore layer removal did not work.
I changed it as I guess it should work. Searching by title [029A, 029C] a polygon is added on the map. Each click removes all polygons before inserting.
Since I removed the global problem `let geoJsonFeatures2=[];` I also removed LayerGroup because it became unnecessary in this case.

Comment: Thank you. Updating the data array globally will  add to not replace. The subtleties of leaflet layers is quite a thing! This adjustment has worked great for swapping data via search on to the layer. Really appreciate the help

Answer (score -1):

You need to keep the geojson layer in a global variable and remove it before over writing with the new layer data.

```
var geoMap2;
function setLaMap(data){
    if(geoMap2) { // if geoMap2 is set remove it
        lamap.removeLayer(geoMap2)
    }

    const geojsonFeatureCollection2 = {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": setFeatureCollection2(data)
    }
    geoMap2 = L.geoJSON(geojsonFeatureCollection2, {
        style: polyStyleLAMap,
        onEachFeature: myonEachFeatureLaMap
    })

.........
```

Comment: Thanks. This makes no difference, repeated searches still fill the opacity.